# How to efficiently shuffle a large tf.data.Dataset when using tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

The [`tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) documentation makes it clear that the input dataset must be properly shuffled for the training to see all examples:

> Overfitting: In order to avoid overfitting, it is recommended to set up the training input_fn to shuffle the training data properly. It is also recommended to train the model a little longer, say multiple epochs, before performing evaluation, as the input pipeline starts from scratch for each training. It is particularly important for local training and evaluation.

In my application, I would like to uniformly sample examples from the full [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) with arbitrary evaluation frequency and [`shuffle()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle)'s buffer size. Otherwise, the training can at most see the first:

```
(steps_per_second * eval_delay * batch_size) + buffer_size
```

elements, effectively discarding the rest. Is there an efficient way to work around that without loading the complete dataset in the system memory?

I considered [sharding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shard) the dataset based on the buffer size, but if the evaluation does not occur frequently, it will iterate on the same shard multiple times (a `repeat()` closes the pipeline). Ideally, I would like to move to another shard after a complete iteration over the dataset, is that possible?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Could you clarify why using the `.shuffle()` method of `Dataset` is not a good option for you?

Comment: I don't want to load the full dataset in the system memory. I clarified my question accordingly.

Comment: You don't load the full dataset with `shuffle`, you have a buffer of a fixed size, which is filled with items from the dataset, from which you take a random sample at every step. While it is true that the buffer is filled from samples taken from a "restricted" area of your input dataset (at least in the first iterations), this in practice is hardly a problem, especially if you shuffled the data in the first place when you made the input dataset.

Comment: The restricted area is the issue when using `train_and_evaluate`. Say the evaluation occurs every 10,000 training steps. With a buffer of size `N`, your training will only see the first 10000 * `batch_size` + `N` examples of your dataset and will never see the rest.

Comment: I see, now I understand your problem, thanks. Sadly, I am not aware of any methods to ensure full shuffling, within the `tf.data` and in other input pipeline frameworks. I remember facing a similar problem and eventually abandoning `train_and_evaluate` specifically for this reason.

Comment: If you read your dataset from a list of filenames (ex: images, or TFRecords), you can shuffle these filenames with a `buffer_size = len(filenames)`, which will only load into memory all the filenames (and not their content).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working with text and the common practice is to gather all data in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

A random sharding of the dataset can be implemented with this Dataset transformation:

```py
def random_shard(shard_size, dataset_size):
  num_shards = -(-dataset_size // shard_size)  # Ceil division.
  offsets = np.linspace(
      0, dataset_size, num=num_shards, endpoint=False, dtype=np.int64)

  def _random_shard(dataset):
    sharded_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(offsets)
    sharded_dataset = sharded_dataset.shuffle(num_shards)
    sharded_dataset = sharded_dataset.flat_map(
        lambda offset: dataset.skip(offset).take(shard_size))
    return sharded_dataset

  return _random_shard
```

This requires to know the total dataset size in advance. However, if you implement a file-based sharding approach, you also iterate on the full dataset once so that is not a major issue.

Regarding efficiency, note that `skip(offset)` actually iterates on `offset` examples so a latency is to be expected if `offset` is large. Careful prefetching should help for this.